# iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Media Queries

Tags: ios, css, media-queries, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Does anyone know specific screen sizes to target media queries for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?

Also, the icon sizes and splash screens?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

## iPhone 6

- Landscape

  ```
  @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 375px) // or 213.4375em or 3in or 9cm
      and (max-device-width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
      and (width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
      and (height : 375px) // or 23.4375em
      and (orientation : landscape) 
      and (color : 8)
      and (device-aspect-ratio : 375/667)
      and (aspect-ratio : 667/375)
      and (device-pixel-ratio : 2)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
  { }
  ```
- Portrait

  ```
  @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 375px) // or 213.4375em
      and (max-device-width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
      and (width : 375px) // or 23.4375em
      and (height : 559px) // or 34.9375em
      and (orientation : portrait) 
      and (color : 8)
      and (device-aspect-ratio : 375/667)
      and (aspect-ratio : 375/559)
      and (device-pixel-ratio : 2)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
  { }
  ```

  *if you prefer you can use `(device-width : 375px)` and `(device-height: 559px)` in place of the `min-` and `max-` settings.*

  *It is not necessary to use all of these settings, and these are not all the possible settings.  These are just the majority of possible options so you can pick and choose whichever ones meet your needs.*
- User Agent

  *tested with my iPhone 6 (model MG6G2LL/A) with iOS 9.0 (13A4305g)*

  ```
  # Safari
  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.39 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13A4305g Safari 601.1
  # Google Chrome
  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10 (000102)
  # Mercury
  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B554a Safari/9537.53
  ```
- Launch images

  - 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
  - 1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape
- App icon

  - 120 x 120

---

#### iPhone 6+

- Landscape

  ```
  @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 414px) 
      and (max-device-width : 736px) 
      and (orientation : landscape) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
  { }
  ```
- Portrait

  ```
  @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 414px) 
      and (max-device-width : 736px)
      and (device-width : 414px)
      and (device-height : 736px)
      and (orientation : portrait) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
  { }
  ```
- Launch images

  - 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
  - 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape
- App icon

  - 180 x 180

---

#### iPhone 6 and 6+

```
@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width: 640px), 
    only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), 
    only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{ }
```

---

### Predicted

According to [the Apple website](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/) the iPhone 6 Plus will have 401 pixels-per-inch and be 1920 x 1080.  The smaller version of the iPhone 6 will be 1334 x 750 with 326 PPI.

So, assuming that information is correct, we can write a media query for the iPhone 6:

```css
@media screen 
    and (min-device-width : 1080px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1920px) 
    and (min-resolution: 401dpi) 
    and (device-aspect-ratio:16/9) 
{ }

@media screen 
    and (min-device-width : 750px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1334px) 
    and (min-resolution: 326dpi) 
{ }
```

Note that [device-aspect-ratio](/questions/tagged/device-aspect-ratio) will be deprecated in http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries-4/ and replaced with [aspect-ratio](/questions/tagged/aspect-ratio)

Min-width and max-width may be something like 1704 x 960.

---

### Apple Watch (speculative)

Specs on the Watch are still a bit speculative since (as far as I'm aware) there has been no official spec sheet yet.  But Apple did mention in [this press release](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/09/09Apple-Unveils-Apple-Watch-Apples-Most-Personal-Device-Ever.html) that the Watch will be available in two sizes.. 38mm and 42mm.

Further assuming.. that those sizes refer to the screen size rather than the overall size of the Watch face these media queries should work.. And I'm sure you could give or take a few millimeters to cover either scenario without sacrificing any unwanted targeting because..

```
@media (!small) and (damn-small), (omfg) { }
```

or

```
@media 
    (max-device-width:42mm) 
    and (min-device-width:38mm) 
{ }
```

It's worth noting that [Media Queries Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/) from W3C currently only available as a first public draft, once available for use will bring with it a lot of new features designed with smaller wearable devices like this in mind.

Comment: And what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762277/iphone-6-and-6-responsive-breakpoints

Comment: @davidcondrey What's with the **Predicted** section in your answer? It contradicts all the (correct) parameters you provided higher up, and the media queries in that **Predicted** section are goofy – width = 1080 and 750? Media query device widths are not based on the actual physical pixel counts of the device, which you clearly know. Was that section added by someone else?

Comment: @LearningFast, I originally wrote this answer before these devices became available and guesstimated what the values might be.  I later edited my answer with the correct values after the devices were released.  I just left the original guesstimations for posterity I guess.

Comment: This was bothering me for so much time -.- , Thank you @davidcondrey U da man! :)

Answer (score 20):

This is what is working for me right now:

iPhone 6

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

iPhone 6+

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 414px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, adding orientation too. Thanks  Fiona!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me for the iphone 6

```
/*iPhone 6 Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) { 

}

/*iPhone 6 landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) { 

}

/*iPhone 6+ Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) { 

}

/*iPhone 6+ landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) { 

}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait and landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : portrait){ 

}

/*iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : landscape){ 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just so you know the iPhone 6 lies about it's min-width.   It thinks it is 320 instead of 375 it is suppose to be.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

This was the only thing I could get to work to target the iPhone 6.   The 6+ works fine the using this method:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-height : 736px) and (max-resolution: 401dpi)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this feedback, i am battling to actually get it right, its quite hard :(

Answer (score 4):

## iPhone X

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  /* uncomment for only portrait: */
  /* and (orientation: portrait) */
  /* uncomment for only landscape: */
  /* and (orientation: landscape) */ { 

}
```

## iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  /* uncomment for only portrait: */
  /* and (orientation: portrait) */
  /* uncomment for only landscape: */
  /* and (orientation: landscape) */ { 

}
```

## iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  /* uncomment for only portrait: */
  /* and (orientation: portrait) */
  /* uncomment for only landscape: */
  /* and (orientation: landscape) */ { 

}
```

Source: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to target screen size using media query for different screen size.

for **iphone**:

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }

@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }
```

and for **desktop** version:

```
@media only screen (max-width: 1080){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone 5,

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)
```

for iPhone 6,7,8

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

for iPhone 6+,7+,8+

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (min-device-width: 414px)
```

Working fine for me as of now.