# iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Responsive Breakpoints

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, media-queries, iphone-6

According to Apple's site:

The iPhone 6 has 1334-by-750-pixel resolution at 326 ppi with 1400:1 contrast ratio (typical)

The iPhone 6+ has 1920-by-1080-pixel resolution at 401 ppi with 1300:1 contrast ratio (typical)

However, what would the CSS media query responsive breakpoints be for each? (portrait and landscape)

I don't fully understand how to test the retina screen sizes using the various responsive emulators out there.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Generally if you are designing a responsive layout you don't design for specific device sizes. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: I understand that.  Im actually designing an App so I wanted to test the exact sizes for the new iphones.

Comment: A good explanation http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Answer (score 55):

You're referencing the physical pixels of the device, rather than the css `device-width` sizes. According to this [tweet](https://twitter.com/kylebarrow/status/509537709929402368), the device-widths for the two will be:

```
iPhone 6: 375px (2.0 DPR)
iPhone 6 Plus: 414px (2.6 DPR)
```

Knowing that (and assuming the tweet is correct), and assuming your using the proper `meta viewport` tag, you're looking at roughly:

```
iPhone 6: 375px (portrait), 667px (landscape)
iPhone 6 Plus: 414 (portrait), 736px (landscape)
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Regarding the `2.6 DPR` of the iPhone 6 Plus, it's actually `3.0 DPR` downsized by `1.15`, which results in `2.6 DPR`. More info can be found at http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified for clarification (thanks @mdcarter for the link!)

Comment: Thanks for the information Jack.  I would up vote your answer by I don't have the reputation.

Comment: Actually the iPhone 6 plus will have a 3 density pixel ratio, but the image is after downscaled for the display.
More informations here : http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: @mdcarter That's really interesting! I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @mdcarter - until I update my css to include 3x, will these devices still render the 2x or revert to 1x?

Answer (score 18):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
    /* iPhone 6 Portrait */ 
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
    /* iPhone 6 landscape */
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
    /* iPhone 6+ Portrait */
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
    /* iPhone 6+ landscape */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
    /* iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait and landscape */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : portrait){ 
    /* iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ portrait */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : landscape){ 
    /* iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ landscape */
}
```

You can get list of media queries for all standard devices [here](http://qnimate.com/overview-of-css3-media-queries/#List_of_mostly_used_media_queries)