# Iphone 6 overflow

Tags: css, css-float

I've got a client's responsive site which is used for mobile purposes only. It works great on every phone except for Iphone 6. Home page loads fine but every inner page gets a weird overflow with a big border at the left side of the screen ([image: see attached image]).

1. Tried to add special breaking points just for Iphone 6 from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762277/iphone-6-and-6-plus-responsive-breakpoints) thread.
2. Tried to add an outer container to the main container with `width:100%;`.
3. Tried to add `overflow:hidden;` to the body and to the inner container.
4. Tried to add `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Nothing worked.

5. Tried to add `position:fixed;` to the body just to see of it will work. The overflow of the screen was gone but the site was of course not scroll-able.

I don't have a mac to debug this issue with developer tools and that limits my options.
On all mobile emulators, Chrome, FF, IE, the site looks o.k. On Browserstack I could see the bug but couldn't debug it there.
It's not a single phone issue, tested on several Iphone 6 devices.

Any other ideas please?

Site [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17641767/hosting/ramot/index.html).

Comment: try border:0px; , lol just a guess

Comment: Looks fine in simulator...

Comment: FWIW, the issue doesn't manifest in Mobile Safari using the "iPhone 6 / iOS 8.1" simulator from Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: At first I thought it's not showing on Browserstack as well but then I double clicked the device's "screen" and the problem showed up after the screen was zoomed out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!
Had an issue with the some uls in the page. Added overflow:hidden; and it solve the problem.