# CSS media query is not properly identifying iphone 6

Tags: ios, css, iphone, web, media-queries

I have a media query that detects mobile phones and displays a mobile version of my site.

As it stands my query is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

This works on pretty much every phone I can find (s3, s4, s5, iphone5 (and below), nexus 5, nexus 6) except for the iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6+. I have tried to alter my query with some things I have found online, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762277/iphone-6-and-6-plus-responsive-breakpoints and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an iPhone5, so I can't test it explicitly on my phone, but I did see these links for other Stack problems.  Could be helpful to you.

http://qnimate.com/overview-of-css3-media-queries/#List_of_mostly_used_media_queries

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions