# What are the "em" breakpoints for iPhones? (Not px sizes)

Tags: ios, iphone, css, media-queries

All of the breakpoint helpers online use pixels. For example: [iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Responsive Breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762277/iphone-6-and-6-plus-responsive-breakpoints). But browsers don't treat `em`ss the same way. There's no set em-to-pixel size that's the same across all phone browsers. So what does the iPhone (iOS Safari) say is the width/height in `em`'s?

Answer (score 2):

An em is not a unit of fixed size, it's a relative measurement based on the parents size. For example setting a body font size of 12 px, then a child element with font size 0.5em, the child will effectively have a font size equivalent to 6px (0.5 * parents size).

Since this is a relative measurement, it does not make sense to define fixed bounds in this way.

Comment: What do you mean? Media Queries have bounds by their nature. You cannot just say in a media query: "start at this size and then scale everything perfectly from that size". You have to set breakpoints.

Comment: I mean, that you cannot pre define what the size of a device will be in ems, as an em does not have a fixed size. In fact, ems are in a way an attempt at: "start at this size and then scale everything perfectly from that size". Please don't down vote correct answers because you don't like / understand them.