# iPhone 6 Plus / iPad Media Query Collide

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, media-queries

I'm trying to target the iPhone 6 Plus in the landscape view.

This is my media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 960px) and (orientation : landscape) {#div { position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:60px;}
```

Somehow the iPad takes this media query too. What did I understand wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See the media queries at [iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Media Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries)

Comment: Oooh, thank you! I got it wrong! They're written wrong here:

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone6