# @media query doesn't trigger for iPhone 6 plus in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries, mobile-safari, screen-orientation

I've been using the following queries based on a pretty popular answer about [standard media queries for iPhone 6 models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries), however, the landscape mode doesn't get picked up. 
What is even more puzzling is that the css written for the portrait media query is still active in landscape mode.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 414px) 
  and (max-device-width : 736px) 
  and (orientation : landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
{ }

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 414px) 
  and (max-device-width : 736px) 
  and (orientation : portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
{ }
```

Did anyone else experienced the same issue and/or is aware of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media only
```

is technically deprecated ( http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries-4/ ), the "only" is not needed so that may be part of the issue.

However, I've not had success w/@media in general on iPhone 6 without targeting at least 1000px.

Their scaling method seems to send the image to the Safari mobile browser at a desktop ~2k resolution then the local device image scaling processes the scale.

It would appear that a new method, or at least more device-specific is required.