# Possible to change layout for phone and tablets using Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I see that there is a responsive grid system for Ionic 2, but that appears to just let you create a grid style layout.

I'm looking for something that will allow me to display the view one way on a tablet, and another on a phone.  In this specific instance, I have a list of jobs.  If it's a tablet, I want to also show a map to the right of the list and plot them out.  How to make the map I understand, but how do I tell what they are using and show the correct UI?

Comment: have you looked into using media queries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052101/ionic-media-queries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could decide how the layout is going to be shown by using the [`platform` information](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/):

```
Platform Name   Description
android on a device running Android.
cordova on a device running Cordova.
core    on a desktop device.
ios on a device running iOS.
ipad    on an iPad device.
iphone  on an iPhone device.
mobile  on a mobile device.
mobileweb   in a browser on a mobile device.
phablet on a phablet device.
tablet  on a tablet device.
windows on a device running Windows.
```

By using the underlying `platform` information you could show or hide things if its a `tablet` (or an `ipad`) by just simply doing:

```
this.isTabletOrIpad = this.platform.is('tablet') || this.platform.is('ipad');
```

And then by using `*ngIf` or whatever you need in your views, or using that `isTabletOrIpad` property to decide whether to initialize the map or not.

Comment: how to use this concept in HTML with ion tag ?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @sebaferreras you can use the names listed in [Platform Name](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#is), but I will suggest using it in conjunction with the `showWhen` attribute.

> The `showWhen` attribute takes a string that represents a platform or
>   screen orientation.  The element the attribute is added to will only
>   be shown when that platform or screen orientation is active.

This approach encapsulates the Platform class logic meaning you don't need to do anything in the Page.ts file, the only code you need to worry about will be in the HTML.

**Example**

If you want certain code to only be visible on a tablet screen

```
<div showWhen="tablet">
    All content inside here will be visible on tablet devices
</div>
```

Se the [ShowWhen](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/) documentation for more information. They also offer a [HideWhen](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/show-hide-when/HideWhen/) attribute too.

**Note**

As mentioned in the comments below

- The `showWhen` approach will just apply the `display: none;` property
  to the element which means your HTML will still be rendered
  regardless of the type of device.
- If you take the `*ngIf` approach it will only load the HTML content
  if it meets the rules.

Performance wise `*ngIf` may be the better option for you, however in other scenarios `showWhen` may be more favourable (I'm trying to keep this generic for other readers).

Comment: I agree with you, but the thing is that by just using `showWhen` in the views, you're still loading a lot of things that you're not going to show later... So why are you going to load and initialize a map in your component code, if later you're not going to show it in the view?