# Make iphone 6 and higher css exclusive using media-queries

Tags: media-queries, iphone-5, iphone-6-plus

I am trying to make iphone 6 & upper models css exclusive of iphone 5S and lower models, but I cannot. I tried running the following on my iphone 6 plus, it does not seem to take any of the styling from here.

```
  /* iphone 6 and higher - landscape */
    @media screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375),
           screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
```

Any suggestion are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries