# Media Queries On iPhone

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I'm trying to use media queries, however they aren't working when I go to my iPhone. When I resize my browser window it works fine though. They look like the following:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){...}
```

And I've including the following meta tag at the top of the file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any idea why it wouldn't be working properly?

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try this:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

You can use [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908234241/https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) as reference for iPhones.