# Media Queries not working for the iPhone 6/6S

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I am designing a [website](http://multiplestreammktg.com) for someone and everything went well and whatever changes I made on the stylesheet including the media queries worked fine except for the media queries for mobile/tablets. Here is my code which I have checked now for the hundredth time and can't seem to find anything syntactically wrong with it.

```
    /*Responsive for iPhone 6 Begin*/

@media screen
and ( min-device-width : 375px) 
and ( max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
    #first-line {
        font-size:30px !Important;  
        letter-spacing:normal !Important;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .index-page-info {
        width: 375px;
    }

    .purechat {
        display: none !Important; 
    } 
}
/*Responsive for iPhone 6 End*/
```

I am developing it on WordPress using the Customizr Pro Child theme. Here is the full style : http://pastebin.com/1u1VMtEz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries

Comment: @ChrisRyer I ave seen it and tried rhat, that makes it not work in the simulator leave alone the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps redundant, but do you have the responsive meta tag in the head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yes, that came with the theme itself there