# Media Queries for iPhone 6 and browser

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries

I have two different media queries, for iPhone and browser. But the iPhone don't work. The sequence is first browser and then iPhone in the style sheet. When i check the site on iPhone and inspect its shows the queries from browser, not from iPhone. What to do??

I saw this: [iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries), But what i want is not there.

Browser:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #my_div li a img {   height: 51% !important;   top: 19% !important;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
   .....
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   .....
}
```

iPhone:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    #my_div li a img { height: 31% !important; top: 14% !important;}
}
```

Comment: Try adding this to the head tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Yes, its already in the head, My site is fully responsive, Now i need to make it iPhone compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target Iphone 6 use;

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px)
```

add orientation only;

```
and (orientation : landscape) OR and (orientation : portrait)
```

For Iphone 6 plus use;

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px)
```

I think at your case <strike>-webkit-device-pixel-ratio</strike> is the reason of it not working.

Comment: No luck, Is it the problem that i also have some queries for 360px and 320px??

Comment: Which one comes first at your code ? Change the locations of the queries, write the one you want most to end of your css file.

Comment: I wrote the iPhone queries at the end of the file, but when i inspect from iPhone device from my browser its not showing the queries for iPhone....

Comment: Remove all the other media queries and try it that way ? If still doesn't work share a code snippet with me

Comment: Removing all the queries does not any solution i think. I need them also.

Comment: Just try and see if it is working. You are not making any sense by saying the media queries are not working. Maybe it is working but you have another css that overrides them all..

Comment: As i told **When i check the site on iPhone and inspect its shows the queries from browser, not from iPhone.**, its not appear in the debug mode.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the cache ?

Answer (score 0):

where is the code for the iphone in the your css? because if it is above the code for the browser your browser code will write over it. if this is the case then you only need to turn it around.

Comment: Why overrides come out?? as i earlier said that **When i check the site on iPhone and inspect its shows the queries from browser, not from iPhone.**