# Why is my media query not applying?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I just wrote a media query for phone displays and it's not applying.  The code in question is below.  For better context, my github page is [here](https://zappacoder.github.io/sgladwin/).  What I'd like is for the food pics to stack and take up the entire width of the screen as seen in the first pic at the bottom.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .food {
    height: 265px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 7rem;
  }
}
```

The media query actually displays somewhat properly when I resize my desktop browser (first pic), but does not work at all on my iPhone 6 (second pic) -- the images are flanked by sizable margins and don't fill the screen.  I say "somewhat properly" because there is a large right margin for when the media query applies on the desktop browser -- you'll see it when you resize your browser when the media query takes effect.  Not sure why that's happening either.  I have a hunch it has to do with how I have my flexbox set up, but I'm not sure.

Here's what I've tried:

-Using the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` meta tag

-Setting the media query to portrait orientation.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the iPhone 6 has a `max-width` of `480px`? See this answer on SO to see the width's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25759240/6773269

Comment: Are you linking to an external CSS file or is it all in the same file? Could copy your page into a JSFiddle or something so we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove only from your media query and write it like this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Also max-width: 480px, does not match with the size of the iPhone 6 screen size. See the following specifications for the actual screen size:

```
(min-width : 375px) // or 213.4375em or 3in or 9cm
(max-width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
```

Comment: Hi Sam Johnson: here is a link to my codepen which has my CSS and HTML: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyyeQO

Comment: @Hoppingvampireprogrammer Why did you comment out your viewport? You need that to be able to correctly style for mobile and tablets!

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed width and heigth for that image class on your Github page, which isn't good for that purpose (small screens).

In the CSS rule for `.food`, change `width` to `100%`, `height` to `auto` (to keep the image proportions intact) and add `box-sizing: border-box` to include the padding into the 100% width. (Or set padding to 0 if you really want the images to span the whole width)

Answer (score -2):

Here's some breakpoints you can use in your code for different devices & orientations:

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```