# Media Query Only for Iphone 6

Tags: css, mobile, resolution

Sorry for my English....

I build a responsive file for my Media Query.

In my `head` Tag, the **meta** Element like this,

> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
>
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
>
> <link rel="preload" href="CSS/xxxx.css" as="style">
>
> <link rel="preload" href="CSS/xxxx" as="style">
>
> <link rel="preload" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" as="script">

I will have my file for Media Query **only** for **any** device. Now to try to build for iPhone 6,

**/* iPhone 6/7/8 , in CSS 667 x 375 (41.6875em x 23.4375em) Landscape  */**

```
@media only screen and (width: 41.6875em) 
                   and (height: 23.4375em) 
                   and (orientation: landscape) 
                   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

**/* iPhone 6/7/8 , in CSS 375 x 667  (23.4375em x 41.6875em ) Portrait  */**

```
@media only screen and (width: 23.4375em) 
                   and (height: 41.6875em) 
                   and (orientation: portrait ) 
                   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

when test my Website with Chrome to come this,
[image]
all to see wonderful..., but **search.google** to show this, it to say **Text to ready too small** and **Clickable elements are too close together**.

[image]

I think my problem is because **width: 23.4375em** and **height: 41.6875em** are not the resolution for iPhone 6, they working only with **max** and **min**. 
I to search on the internet and only [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries) with **min-device-width** and 
**max-device-widt**,

My question, how can have Media Query for iPhone 6, without **max** and **min**, only with **width** and **height**.

Can please help me, anyone, with this problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know because before to come to this problem...

I trying to target an exact screen size with inexact units. Because I have not found an exact screen size for iPad 6, I will write the Media Query as I to see in Internet...

/* iPhone 6/7/8 , in CSS 667 x 375 (41.6875em x 23.4375em) Landscape */

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 23.4375em) 
               and (max-device-width: 41.6875em) 
               and (orientation: landscape) 
               and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

/* iPhone 6/7/8 , in CSS 375 x 667 (23.4375em x 41.6875em ) Portrait */

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 23.4375em) 
               and (max-device-width: 41.6875em) 
               and (orientation: portrait ) 
               and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ }
```

How to show now on **search.google**

[image]